# Scatterplot seaborn that supports subplots and hue

Tags: python-2.7, grid, seaborn, scatter-plot, subplot

I want to plot some data with scatter plot by sqft_living x price and use the "hue=" to see the patterns... But I am not getting.

```
plt.figure(figsize = (12,8))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.4, top = 0.8)


ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
ax1 = sns.countplot(x="bathrooms", data=df_usa,
                    ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xticklabels(ax1.get_xticklabels(),rotation=90)
ax1.set_title("Bathrooms counting", fontsize=15)
ax1.set_xlabel("Bathrooms number")
ax1.set_ylabel("count")

ax2 = plt.subplot(222)
ax2 = sns.boxplot(x="bathrooms", y='price', jitter=True,
                  data=df_usa, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_xticklabels(ax2.get_xticklabels(),rotation=90)
ax2.set_title("Bathrooms distribution price", fontsize=15)
ax2.set_xlabel("Bathrooms number")
ax2.set_ylabel("log Price(US)")

ax0 = plt.subplot(212)
ax0 = sns.regplot(x="sqft_living", y="price", #I need to add hue="bathrooms"
                    data=df_usa)
ax0.set_title("Better understaning price", fontsize=15)
ax0.set_xlabel("Sqft Living")
ax0.set_ylabel("log Price(US)")
ax0.set_xticklabels(ax0.get_xticklabels(),rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

I need the output like this:
[output of cod with using ax.plot...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57NL2.jpg)

please, remember that I need to use seaborn.

Comment: `regplot` does not have a `hue` argument. You cannot use a non-existing argument. Hence why not use the solution you already have `ax.plot`? Because every seaborn plot **is** a matplotlib plot, "I need to use seaborn" seems not very reasonable, but maybe you want to explain the problem more in detail.

Comment: Hey my friend, I want one solution that I can use scatter + hue with subplots...

Comment: I sure understand that. But as said, the regplot does not have a `hue` argument. So given that this is impossible you need to opt for the second best option to achieve what you want and that would be `plt.plot()` looping over the different bathrooms or `plt.scatter` with the different bathrooms as color codes. Because you were actually able to produce such plot yourself, it would be necessary to tell in how far this is not what you want.